# What age would Jack Napier (The Joker) be while fighting The Batman?

Tags: batman-1989

In the movie [Batman (1989)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_(1989_film)), Jack Napier/The Joker is shown to have killed Bruce Wayne's parents, Thomas and Martha Wayne. Jack Napier looks like he would have been in his mid-20s or early 30s during the shooting. And Bruce would have been around 8-12 years of age. So later on, when Bruce eventually becomes the Batman fights the Joker, wouldn't their age gap be a lot larger than what's portrayed by Michael Keaton and Jack Nicholson?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Jack Nicholson and Michael Keaton are 14 years apart.  Remember that Gabrielle Carteris was 21 when she first started filming Beverly Hills 90210, when she was supposed to be 17-ish in age for the role.  Assuming Joker was in his early 20's when he killed Bruce's parents, and Bruce was roughly 8, you're talking about maybe a 5 year difference in Nicholson's actual age vs the age he portrayed Joker to be?  Definitely plausible.

So, to answer the question, Batman would be mid-to-late 30's and Joker would be about 50.  That's pretty much what it looked like on screen.

Comment: Where did you get "mid-to-late 40's"?

Comment: "Assuming Joker was in his early 20's when he killed Bruce's parents, and Bruce was roughly 8, you're talking about maybe a 5 year difference in Nicholson's actual age vs the age he portrayed Joker to be" — 8 plus 14 is 22, so it looks more like a 0-year difference to me.

Comment: While watching the movie, I thought Jack Napier was in his 30s and not about 50.

Comment: There is a TV Trope "Dawson casting" for adult actors protraying teenages, but there are even more extreme age differences between actors and characters.  I know of a television episode where a fictional version of a historical character who lived to be 14 is protrayed by an actor 4 times that age who didn't look younger than his real age.   https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DawsonCasting